# ASP.NET MVC Ошибка 0x800a1391 - Ошибка выполнения JavaScript: "$"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Учусь. Разбираю лекцию ITVDN MVC4 WebApi, вторая лекция. Не знаю в чем проблема..уже скопировал полностью все части проекта кроме web.congig.  Весь код проверил, все совпадает. У меня хром и MSEdge просто молчит в момент когда пытается запустить аякс процес, а  InternetExplorer выдает ошибку на этот моменте 
" $.ajax({" - стока три

> 0x800a1391 - Ошибка выполнения JavaScript: "$" не определено

код функции:

```
(function () {
// Функция вызывается при загрузке скрипта и делает асинхронный запрос на сервер
$.ajax({   //- ошибка тут!

    url: "/api/Fruits",

    success: function (names) {

        var list = $("#names"); // находим элемент на странцие

        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) { // names - JSON объект полученый со стороны сервера.
            var name = names[i];
            list.append("<li>" + name + "</li>");
        }
    }
    //,

    //error: function (data2) {
    //    alert("Элемен по указанному индексу не найден.");
    //}

});

// после загрузки документа, находим на страцние кнопку и добавляем метод getName как обработчик на событие click
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").on("click", getName);
});

function getName() {

    // uri в формате /api/names/5
    var link = "/api/fruits/" + $("#elementId").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: "GET",

        // в случае успешной обработки запроса
        success: function (data) {
            $("#receivedElement").text(data); // вывод результата
        },

        // в случае ошибки
        error: function (xhr) {

            if (xhr.status == "404") {
                alert("Элемен по указанному индексу не найден.");
                $("#receivedElement").text(xhr.responseText);
            }
            if (xhr.status == "500") {
                alert("Ошибка сервера");
            }

        }
    });
};
})();
```

Вьювер вроде тоже правильно прописан, там ничего сложно..ссылка на скрипт и теги для отображения

Comment: jQuery не загрузился к моменту вызова? Ссылка на библиотеку должна быть выше первого использования. Web API тут вряд ли играет роль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь запустить функцию jQuery - Ajax без подключения её библиотеки, объявите во вьюшке загрузку библиотеки:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Также в виду безобразия со стороны РКН советую скачать библиотеку и подключить ее локально а не стягивать с гугла

Comment: спасибо..все работает. Поставил вашу ссылку, все заработало. И я нашел корень у себя ошибки. Я скопировал строку библиотеки из примера 2016 года а там старая версия библиотеки <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1..min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/CustomScripts/getName.js"></script>  У меня же новая студия ставит..исправил на версию 1.10.2. и все запустилось